# cross compile driver

Tags: drivers, arm, cross-compilation

I have a cross compile environment setup to compile for an ARM 9 processor, this works fine, now I want to compile an external third party driver within this environment.

I downloaded the driver, and copied it into a directory. When I now call `make`, the compiler can't find the headers because the references are made from `../`.

So what I get is:

```
$ make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions Module.* modules.order
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-14-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/reg/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/reg/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi/GobiSerial.o
In file included from include/linux/types.h:5:0,
                 from include/linux/list.h:4,
                 from include/linux/wait.h:5,
                 from include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from include/linux/tty.h:4,
                 from /home/reg/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi/GobiSerial.c:47:
include/uapi/linux/types.h:4:23: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [/home/reg/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi/GobiSerial.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/reg/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios/ACME/linux-3.11.6/Gobi$
```

How do I get this to compile properly?

Comment: Don't you just need to add an additional switch to your `make ...` command?

Comment: @slm maybe, but what switch? `make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-` is how I can compile the kernel in `../`

Comment: I did find this example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/fnGpkzp9GkQ. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: What directory are you running `make` from?